# JavaScript: Code doesn't move one element

Tags: javascript, html

I started to make a slideshow processing/creating script.
But in my test it moves 2 images in the `slide_container` out of 3 and one just rests there where it was. So the question is what the error?

Javascript:

```
    "use strict";
window.SlideJS = {
    version: "0.1.0",
    options:
    {
        slides_place: "",
        delay: 1000,
        arrows:
        {
            areThey: !0,
            hover_backgroundColor: "#f0e68c",
            hover_color: "#000",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            color: "#000"
        },
        slides:
        {
            get_type: "src",
            className: "mySlides",
            inDIV: !1,
            slides_src: [
        "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg",
        "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg",
        "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg"]
        }
    },
    slide: []
};
var SlideJS = window.SlideJS,
    construct = function ()
    {
        var e = document.createElement("div");
        e.className = "slide_container";
        var s = SlideJS.options.slides_place ? SlideJS.options.slides_place : document.body;
        if (s.appendChild(e), "class" == !SlideJS.options.slides.get_type)
            for (var l, i = SlideJS.options.slides.slides_src.length, d = 0; d < i; d++) {
                (l = document.createElement("img")).src = SlideJS.options.slides.slides_src[d],
                l.className = SlideJS.options.slides.className,
                document.body.appendChild(l);
            }
            SlideJS.slide = document.getElementsByClassName(SlideJS.options.slides.className),
            i = SlideJS.slide.length;
        for ( d = 0; d < i; d++)
        {
            if (SlideJS.options.slides.inDIV)
            {
                var o = document.createElement("div");
                e.appendChild(o), o.className = SlideJS.options.slides.className,
                s = o;
            }
            else s = e;
            s.appendChild(SlideJS.slide[d]);
        }
    };
```

If i use `src` it gets worse: it just doesn't do anything.
The html code that i used is:

```
<div class="content display-container" style="max-width:800px">
  <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides animate-opacity" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

I looked at the HTML structure with the console.[Click here to see the 3 images and that they aren't in the same div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRO1m.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you done to debug this, and what is your question?

Comment: I cant get, do you initiate somewhere on document ready, for ex., your SlideJS like mySlide = new SlideJS(); ?

Comment: I type this in the console "construct();"